# Filled fields after HttpPost Create - object is null using input

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm studying ASP.NET MVC 5. I created a View "Create". But I'm not using Razor to generate the input fields, I'm using inputs with pure html.

**Create.cshtml**

```
@model MyProject.Product

<h2>Create Product</h2>

<form method="post">

    Description: <br /> 
    <input type="text"  name="Description" id="Description"/> <br />
    ValueType: <br />
    <input type="text" name="ValueType" id="ValueType"/>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="btSend"/>

</form>
```

My Controller:

```
   public ActionResult Create()
        {            
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Product product)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {                
                db.Product.Add(product);                
                db.SaveChanges();                
                return RedirectToAction("Index");

            }
            else
            {
                return View(product);
            }

    It works fine. I can create new products.
```

But I need to use some server-side validations with Annotations in the Model.
So, I would like to send the data and, if the model is not valid, go back to the Create with the values. I know how to put the validation messages. So, I tried this:

```
  @model MyProject.Product

<h2>Create Product</h2>

<form method="post">

    Description: <br /> 
    <input type="text"  name="Description" id="Description" value="@Model.Description"/> <br />
    ValueType: <br />
    <input type="text" name="ValueType" id="ValueType" value="@Model.ValueType"/>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="btSend"/>

</form>
```

How to bind pure input with html to model?

Why null value?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why in the world are you not using razor? Generate you form controls correctly using `@Html.LabelFor()`, `@Html.TextBoxFor()` and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` - and then look at all the html it generates and compare that with your which means you do not have 2-way model binding and no validation

Comment: Because  I work with front-end developers that gives me the html created. I want to know if there's a way to work with input type. How to bind it?

Comment: Using the `HtmlHelper` methods will give you the correct html that is necessary for 2-way model binding and validation. And `@Model.Description` is razor code so there is no point saying you do not want to use razor

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `razor based form approach`, you can use display validation message with `Viewbag/ViewData`.

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Product product)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {   
            //if you want to get validation message from ModelState itself, you can query from Modelstate :
           string message = string.Join(" , ", ModelState.Values
                              .SelectMany(v => v.Errors)
                               .Select(e => e.ErrorMessage));
            ViewData["ValidationMessage"] = "Validation Message";// you can use above variable message here
            return View(product);
        }
     // your other implementation
    }
```

Your view should be like this :

```
@model MyProject.Product

<h2>Create Product</h2>

<form method="post">
    <div class="error-message">@ViewData["ValidationMessage"]</div>
    Description: <br /> 
    <input type="text"  name="Description" id="Description" value="@Model.Description"/> <br />
    ValueType: <br />
    <input type="text" name="ValueType" id="ValueType" value="@Model.ValueType"/>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="btSend"/>

</form>
```

But, I would recommend to use `razor based form approach` if you are allowed to do so.

Comment: You solution **is** using razor (that's what the `@` in `@ViewData["ValidationMessage"]` signifies.

Comment: yeah but OP is already using some simple razor too like "@Model.Description" and "@Model.ValueType"

Comment: Yes I know (as I noted in the comments to the question). But your question states _If you don't want to use razor_ but then show a solution using razor :)

Comment: I've corrected it now, calling it as razor based form approach.

Comment: It's razor, but I liked this for validation messages. I just wanna keep the values.  But the problem is: How to keep the values?

Comment: I am not sure, which value do you want to keep?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may misunderstand the razor view engine.  Pages 2.0 and 3.0 (razor) does not have databinding in any way.  It emulates it with the html helpers, but this is not native razor databinding.  Take a look at the code behind s could of the helpers (https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/DefaultEditorTemplates.cs) and you will see they are just performing the work that you are hoping for.